# How to avoid moving on to the next one if the fields are not complete?

Tags: jquery

In a simple and simple way how to avoid going to the next step if the fields are empty, that the same message is displayed for all fields, regardless of the type of field that is `input, textarea, select, radio, checkbox` among others, show below the field the following message "This field must be completed to continue".

Once all the fields are filled then move on to the next one and so on.

This is the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/sLw19vh2/

Comment: *FORCING* the poor user isn't a good idea.  This article discusses some "friendlier" alternatives: https://www.sitepoint.com/instant-validation/

Comment: @paulsm4 the required aspect damages the design, I don't like it, the use of this implementation is for the administration system, it is not so much for common users.

Comment: because the negative vote, I observe questions without code, practically asking them to do a project to them and, they are welcome, it is not fair I have my code I just needed a little help :/ :(

Comment: @Mary When I see valid()  you are using jQuery Validation Plugin ? And is it enough just checking if it's empty ! Because It could be not empty but not valid :) People usually count on plugins for such process like jQuery steps + jQuery validate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target different input types, the best way is to use a unique shared classname like here `icon-mail`.. And set the required property, this way we could count on browser validation and that we could use as jQuery selector filter when needed.

As being asked by the question, this is a minimalist change to prevent skipping a form step when this level' inputs are empty.

Another approach you can work on is instant validation by using `.on('change keyup...')` to trigger a function that validates current level fields, change styling count them and toggle the button visibility.

```js
$(function () {
  $("body").on("keyup", "form", function(e){
   if (e.which == 13){
    if ($("#next-wizard").is(":visible") && $("fieldset.current-wizard").find("input, textarea").valid() ){
     e.preventDefault();
     nextSection();
     return false;
    }
   }
  });

            
  $("#next-wizard").on("click", function(e){
        var notEmpty=$('fieldset.current-wizard .icon-mail[required]').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val();
        }).length;
        var reqElms=$('fieldset.current-wizard .icon-mail[required]').length;
   //console.log(e.target);
            if(notEmpty==reqElms){
            $('.sms').empty();
            $('.errtxt').remove();
            $('fieldset.current-wizard .icon-mail[required]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).addClass("success");
         nextSection();
            } else{
            e.preventDefault();
            
$('fieldset.current-wizard .icon-mail[required]').filter(function() {
   if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
     $(this).removeClass('success').addClass("error");
     $(this).parent().append('<span class="errtxt">This fields must be completed to continue!</span>');
   }
});
                
            }
  });
  $("form").on("submit", function(e){
   if ($("#next-wizard").is(":visible") || $("fieldset.current-wizard").index() < 3){
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  });
  function goToSection(i){
   $("fieldset:gt("+i+")").removeClass("current-wizard").addClass("next-wizard");
   $("fieldset:lt("+i+")").removeClass("current-wizard");
   $("li").eq(i).addClass("current-wizard").siblings().removeClass("current-wizard");
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("fieldset").eq(i).removeClass("next-wizard").addClass("current-wizard active-wizard");
    if ($("fieldset.current-wizard").index() == 3){
     $("#next-wizard").hide();
     $(".indicate").show();
    } else {
     $("#next-wizard").show();
     $(".indicate").hide();
    }
   }, 80);
  }
  function nextSection(){
   var i = $("fieldset.current-wizard").index();
   if (i < 3){
    $("li").eq(i+1).addClass("active-wizard");
    goToSection(i+1);
   }
  }
 
  $("li").on("click", function(e){
   var i = $(this).index();
   if ($(this).hasClass("active-wizard")){
    goToSection(i);
   } else {
    alert("Please complete previous sections first.");
   }
  });
 });
```

```css
.error{
border:2px solid red !important;
}
.success{
border:2px solid green !important;
}
.wizard-form {
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 80px auto;
 position: relative;
 min-height: 300px;
}
ul#section-tabs {
 font-size: 0.8em;
 height: 50px;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 padding: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
#section-tabs li {
 color: #a7a7a7;
 cursor: not-allowed;
 border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0 6px;
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 30px;
 background: #ddd;
 position: relative;
}
#section-tabs li span {
 color: #bababa;
}
#section-tabs li.active-wizard {
 color: #444;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#section-tabs li:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 margin-left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
#section-tabs li.current-wizard {
 opacity: 1;
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 999;
 border-left: none;
}
#section-tabs li.current-wizard:after {
 border: 15px solid transparent;
 border-left: 15px solid #2cbab2;
}
.error {
 color: #bf2424;
 display: block;
}
input.error,
textarea.error {
 border-color: #bf2424;
}
input.error:focus,
textarea.error:focus {
 border-color: #bf2424;
}
label.error {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input.valid {
 color: green;
}
label.valid {
 position: absolute;
 right: 20px;
}
input + .valid,
textarea + .valid {
 display: none;
}
.valid + .valid {
 display: inline;
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 margin-top: -36px;
 color: green;
}
.btn-wizard {
 border: none;
 padding: 8px;
 background: #2cbab2;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;
 right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}
.btn-wizard:hover {
 background: #26a19a;
}


div#fieldsets {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
}
fieldset {
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: -640px;
 width: 600px;
 padding: 10px 0;
 transition: all 0.3s linear;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
 opacity: 0;
}
fieldset.current-wizard {
 left: 20px;
 opacity: 1;
}
fieldset.next-wizard {
 left: 640px;
}
.indicate {
 display: none;
 border: none;
}

#next-wizard{
/*display:none;*/
}
.field {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 min-height: 75px;
}
.field input[type="email"], .field input[type="password"], .field input[type="text"], .form-defaul input[type="email"], .form-defaul input[type="password"], .form-defaul input[type="text"], .form-defaul select, .field select {
 padding: 25px 10px 10px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: transparent;
 outline: 0;
 border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 color: #888;
 height: 55px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.field label, .form-defaul label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 8px;
 left: 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #888;
}
.field label.required:after, .form-defaul label.required:after {
 content: "*";
 color: tomato;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
/*option:disabled { color: red; }*/
.field-block  {
 width: 100%;
}
.field-half {
 width: 50%;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wizard-form">
<div class="sms"></div>
           <form>
            <ul id="section-tabs">
             <li class="current-wizard active-wizard"><span>1.</span> Creds</li>
             <li><span>2.</span> Deets</li>
             <li><span>3.</span> Settings</li>
             <li><span>4.</span> Last Words</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="fieldsets">
             <fieldset class="current-wizard">
              <div class="form-group">
               <div class="field field-block">
                <input class="icon-mail" type="text" name="first_name" required>
                <label class="required">Nombre</label>
               </div>
               <div class="field field-block">
                <input class="icon-mail" type="email" name="email" required>
                <label class="required">Email</label>
               </div>
              </div>
             </fieldset>
             <fieldset class="next-wizard"></fieldset>
             <fieldset class="next-wizard"></fieldset>
             <fieldset class="next-wizard"></fieldset>

             <a class="btn-wizard" id="next-wizard">Next Section ▷</a>
             <input type="submit" class="indicate btn-wizard">
            </div>
           </form>
          </div>
```